# How do I scale an Azure Cloud Service using SDK 2.4?

Tags: c#, azure

I seem to recall, that in the past, there was WASABi in Enterprise Library 5, which was used in order to scale Azure Cloud Services.

I've recently installed Enterprise Library 6 and noticed that WASABi is not a part of it.

- How do I scale an Azure Cloud Service deployment nowadays?
- Is it possible to set up the scaling solution locally for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I scale an Azure Cloud Service deployment nowadays?

If you're looking to scale Azure Cloud Service in the cloud (and not on local emulator), you can make use of `Azure Auto Scaling`. You may find this link useful for that: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-scale/.

> Is it possible to set up the scaling solution locally for testing?

It is not possible to do so in SDK 2.4. This is one of the [`breaking changes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn794167.aspx) in SDK 2.4. From the SDK 2.4 release notes:

> The Full Compute Emulator is deprecated- The Full Compute Emulator is
>   deprecated in SDK 2.4.  As with SDK 2.3, all new Cloud Services
>   projects now use Emulator Express by default.  Emulator Express allows
>   you to test your multi-role Cloud Services locally without requiring
>   administrator privileges.  **Unlike Full Compute Emulator, however,
>   Emulator Express only supports one instance per role.**

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thanks for the quick reply. In your opinion : WASABi is not usable any longer - correct?

Comment: Since I haven't used WASABi, I may not be the best person to answer that question. But given that it is not there in Enterprise Library 6, it is a good indication that one should not be using it going forward -  Just my personal thought. HTH.